# Devise sign-in not working in IE through an iframe

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, iframe, devise

I don't see any error messages in the log file, and there is no message on the screen. Logging in to my Rails 3 app as it is served up in an iframe from another site results in being returned to the main site without the user being logged in.

It sounds like the Rails app is not recognizing the cookie through the iframe. Has anyone else run into this problem? Where could I go to see what the error is?

Please note this ONLY occurs in IE, version 8 (maybe it occurs in 7 and 6, haven't tested yet).

Comment: I'd recommend using a popup or separate screen. See my comment below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

James is correct, IE has some security in place to prevent iFrames from generating cookies. There's an easy fix for this, simply include the following response header into your controller:

```
response.headers['P3P'] = 'CP="NON DSP COR CURa IVAa IVDa CONa OUR NOR STA"'
```

Source: http://adamyoung.net/IE-Blocking-iFrame-Cookies

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems with IE 6 and 7 and Devise with iframes. From my understanding it has something to do with sessions not being passed through iframes in IE. According to what I was able fo find, IE prevents this for security.

I'm not sure why this only seems to be a security issue in IE and not other browsers.

Comment: Yes, this is a security "feature" and it will most likely effect IE 7/8, but not IE 6. I have done some really crazy stuff to get around this in the past for other things.